Phonepe PG API - 429 On UAT/Sandbox URL
I am getting 429 while calling the API endpoint https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/pay. Using the merchant id PGTESTPAYUAT as mentioned in their documentation and salt key as they provided in the onboarding email.
Following is the response
{
  success: false,
  code: 'TOO_MANY_REQUESTS',
  message: 'Too many requests. Please try again.',
  data: {}
}

Documentation : https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/pay-api-1
Thanks in advance!
